# Is it possible in Delphi to have a callable object like I can do in Python using the __call__() method?

Tags: python, delphi, object, callable

As the question says, using Python I am able to do something like this:

```py
class myCallableClass(object):
    def __call__(self, value):
        return 'myCallableClass: ' + value


my_instance = myCallableClass()

# I am calling the istance of my class like a function
my_var = my_instance('string')

print(my_var) # prints 'myCallableClass: string'
```

Is there a way to achieve something similar in Delphi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in Delphi like a Python callable object. Or a C++ function call operator().

Comment: I knew that you would be the one answering me as you replied as first to all my delphi/python questions. I'll take your answer as good. :) Thank you.